# how to use a fragment shader without main function

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl

i found a shader to do a drop shadow from http://madebyevan.com/shaders/fast-rounded-rectangle-shadows/

```
// License: CC0 (http://creativecommons.org/publicdomain/zero/1.0/)

// This approximates the error function, needed for the gaussian integral
vec4 erf(vec4 x) {
   vec4 s = sign(x), a = abs(x);
   x = 1.0 + (0.278393 + (0.230389 + 0.078108 * (a * a)) * a) * a;
   x *= x;
   return s - s / (x * x);
}

// Return the mask for the shadow of a box from lower to upper
float boxShadow(vec2 lower, vec2 upper, vec2 point, float sigma) {
   vec4 query = vec4(point - lower, upper - point);
   vec4 integral = 0.5 + 0.5 * erf(query * (sqrt(0.5) / sigma));
   return (integral.z - integral.x) * (integral.w - integral.y);
}
```

i thought that a shader need a main function and should return color.
My question is how to use the function boxShadow in c++ code with opengl given a box
thanks

Comment: You can define functions in glsl, so I think you are supposed to call the function from your main function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A function can be defined in a shader just as you would do with a C function. I mean, the code for the function is in the same "unit" as the rest of the shader.

```
#version XX-YY

//MyFunc(.....)
whateverreturn MyFunc(.....)
{
    do something and return a whateverreturn  
}

void main(void)
{
    //use MyFunc
    whateverreturn var = MyFunc(....)
}
```

A bit different case is when you have a function that can be part of several shaders, but it isn't a "full" shader, it has no `main()` function. This function lives in a file or in string-array or something similar.

Say you have the function in a specific file:

```
#version XX-YY

//MyFunc(.....)
whateverreturn MyFunc(.....)
{
    do something and return a whateverreturn  
}
```

And the file with the shader where you want to use it:

```
#version XX-YY

//declare the function
whateverreturn MyFunc(.....);

void main(void)
{
    //use MyFunc
    whateverreturn var = MyFunc(....)
}
```

Like you do with any common GLSL code, use `glShaderSource` and `glCompileShader`.

Now the key step is how to integrate the code within a *full* (with 'main') shader: just use `glAttachShader` (again, like you do with VS or FS)  before `glLinkProgram` and that'as all.

Comment: Thanks ! And do you know how to apply gaussian integral to a image

Comment: @rawinput Please, don't mix questions. Search SO, or the web, or ask a new question.